# Measure of "subspace", has it a sense?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let for exemple $(\mathbb R^3,m_3)$ where $m_3$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^3$ and $(\mathbb R^2,m_2)$ with it's Lebesgue measure $m_2$. We now define the measure $m$ of $\mathbb R^2$ with the exterior mesure $$m^*(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty |B_i|\mid B_i=\mathcal B_i\cap \mathbb R^2, E\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \mathcal B_i\right\}.$$
So $\mathcal B_i$ are balls of $\mathbb R^3$ and $B_i$ are balls of $\mathbb R^2$ but obtained form balls of $\mathbb R^3$ and $E\subset \mathbb R^2$.

My question is the following one: Is there a constant $C$ s.t. $$m_2(E)=Cm(E)$$
or at least $C,D$ s.t. $$Cm_2(E)\leq m(E)\leq Dm_2(E).$$

What I in fact would like to do, is to define a measure of subspace, but I'm not sure if it really has a sense.

Answer (score 1):

Every ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be obtained by projecting balls in $\mathbb{R}^3$: say $B$ is a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with center $(x,y)$ and radius $r$; let $\mathcal{B}$ be the ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with center $(x,y,0)$ and radius $r$, then "$\mathcal{B}\cap \mathbb{R}^2= B$" in your notation.

So $m=m_2$.